# Standby (Sleep) CMD

Tags: windows-xp, sleep, batch-file

I wanted to know how to **standby (sleep)** from command prompt for Windows XP. Using this CMD command `C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0` didn't work alone.

The only way I have found is to make a .bat file, then insert this code:

```
powercfg -h off
start /min "" C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
:: waiting 4 seconds for sleep
ping -n 4 127.0.0.1 > nul 
powercfg -h on
exit
```

...and whenever I open that file, the computer sleeps.

Is there an easier way to do this? I don't want external programs, just from cmd.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but searching for a user, who needs the command line for sleep. The most of the sleep commands are triggered by the external programs, but in XP, there doesnt seem to be only one-line command.

Comment: Well I would see it as duplicate, as you would get the same answer as you can find that that question.

Comment: @JesperJensen : seems to me that the asker clearly states that the one-line solution (which is the one given in the question you link) doesn't work for him.

Comment: @Levans It is also clearly stated in the duplicate topic and other answers has also been posted above. It's generally the same question, why should he get different answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in “one line”, try

> `powercfg -h off & start /min "" C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 & ping -n 4 127.0.0.1 > nul & powercfg -h on`

but I believe that the `.bat` file is easier.  :-)